# Spring Boot app terminates with JdbcSqlSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, h2, spring-jdbc

This is the application class:

```
package ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LearnJpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LearnJpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is the commandlinerunner class:

```
package ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot.course.jdbc;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot.course.Course;

@Component
public class CourseJdbcCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private CourseJdbcRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        repository.insert(new Course(1, "Learn AWS Now!", "In28minutes"));
    }

}
```

This is the class used to modify the h2 database

```
    package ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot.course.jdbc;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot.course.Course;

@Repository
public class CourseJdbcRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate springJdbcTemplate;

    private static String INSERT_QUERY =
            """
            insert into course(id,name,author)
            value(?,?,?);
            """;

    public void insert(Course course) {
        springJdbcTemplate.update
        (INSERT_QUERY, course.getId(), course.getName(), course.getAuthor());
    }
}
```

This is the Class whose object is used to store the sql data:

```
    public class Course {
    public Course() {

    }

    public Course(long id, String name, String author) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
    }

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String author;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", author=" + author + "]";
    }
}
```

This is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ronit</groupId>
    <artifactId>Learn-JPA-and-Hibernate-with-Spring-Boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Learn-JPA-and-Hibernate-with-Spring-Boot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The Application.properties file

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

The Schema.sql file

```
create table course(
id bigint not null,
name varchar(255) not null,
author varchar(255) not null ,
primary key (id)
);
```

This is the console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

2023-06-24T13:06:07.712+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] JpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication : Starting LearnJpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 7764 (C:\All Spring Project Files\Learn-JPA-and-Hibernate-with-Spring-Boot\Learn-JPA-and-Hibernate-with-Spring-Boot\target\classes started by dkent in C:\All Spring Project Files\Learn-JPA-and-Hibernate-with-Spring-Boot\Learn-JPA-and-Hibernate-with-Spring-Boot)
2023-06-24T13:06:07.716+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] JpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-24T13:06:07.771+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-06-24T13:06:07.772+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-06-24T13:06:08.477+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-06-24T13:06:08.478+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-24T13:06:08.502+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-06-24T13:06:08.517+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-06-24T13:06:08.518+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-24T13:06:08.526+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-06-24T13:06:09.188+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-24T13:06:09.198+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-24T13:06:09.200+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
2023-06-24T13:06:09.284+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-24T13:06:09.287+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1512 ms
2023-06-24T13:06:09.320+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-06-24T13:06:09.514+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA
2023-06-24T13:06:09.516+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-06-24T13:06:09.529+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2023-06-24T13:06:09.700+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-06-24T13:06:09.765+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.5.Final
2023-06-24T13:06:09.767+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-06-24T13:06:09.905+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-06-24T13:06:10.057+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-06-24T13:06:10.194+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-06-24T13:06:10.399+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-06-24T13:06:10.407+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-24T13:06:10.497+05:30  WARN 7764 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-06-24T13:06:10.931+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-06-24T13:06:10.967+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-24T13:06:10.980+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] JpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication : Started LearnJpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication in 3.974 seconds (process running for 4.908)
2023-06-24T13:06:10.999+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-24T13:06:11.020+05:30 ERROR 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot.LearnJpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication.main(LearnJpaAndHibernateWithSpringBootApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into course(id,name,author)
value(?,?,?);
]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:101) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1538) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1025) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot.course.jdbc.CourseJdbcRepository.insert(CourseJdbcRepository.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot.course.jdbc.CourseJdbcRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.insert(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at ronit.LearnJPAandHibernatewithSpringBoot.course.jdbc.CourseJdbcCommandLineRunner.run(CourseJdbcCommandLineRunner.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "insert into course(id,name,author)\000a[*]value(?,?,?);\000a"; expected "OVERRIDING USER VALUE, OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE, DIRECT, SORTED, DEFAULT VALUES, VALUES, SET, WITH, (, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES"; SQL statement:
insert into course(id,name,author)
value(?,?,?);
 [42001-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:261) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:900) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:5675) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2766) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2633) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2612) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2605) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2598) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2567) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1669) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:666) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1637) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2023-06-24T13:06:11.049+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-24T13:06:11.268+05:30  WARN 7764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-214]
2023-06-24T13:06:11.269+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-06-24T13:06:11.274+05:30  INFO 7764 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I cannot understand why it is getting terminated I am following a udemy course for this and I think I did everything right still my app is not starting and throwing this error

I am using Spring boot : 3.1.1 for this project .

Comment: I cannot find out how to solve this problem the application just terminates and I am unable to do anything about it I don't know where I have made the mistake in this project

Comment: Typo in your SQL insert statement.  Use: `values (?, ?, ?)`

Comment: Thanks in advance to whoever is going to help me  please tell any solution this is very urgent . I think this much details are sufficient but tell me if more details are required .

Comment: Fix your typo and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen I was not expecting so fast a reply it works I thought that value would also work fine as it worked when I used mysql anyways you saved much of my time tag it as an answer and I will  accept it

Comment: Answers which only fix minor typos are generally not posted as answers.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax is not correct in you [insert statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp), it must be `values`, not `value`:

```
insert into course(id,name,author) values(?,?,?);
```